# Install a Program from a Directory with All of Its Dependencies

Tags: installation, apt, dependencies

Suppose I have a directory in which I have `.deb` packages for two programs with all there dependencies. I want to know if there is a `apt` or `dpkg` command, or `another program` to install one out of these two programs with all their dependencies. The dependencies should be installed automatically as I install the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `apt-offline` for this. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) for this!

1. Download `apt-offline` package on your Networked PC from packages.ubuntu.com. `wget http://ubuntu.hitsol.net/ubuntu//pool/universe/a/apt-offline/apt-offline_1.1.1build1_all.deb`
2. Copy apt-offline_1.1.1build1_all.deb to your **NON-Networked** Notebook
   using an USB-Stick
3. Next install it there: `sudo dpgk -i apt-offline_1.1.1build1_all.deb`
4. Now say you want to install a package called cuckoo on the **NON-Networked** Notebook execute this command on the **NON-Networked** Notebook:`sudo apt-offline set cuckoo-offline.sig --install-packages cuckoo`
5. Copy the file cuckoo-offline.sig to the Networked PC and run this command:`sudo apt-offline get cuckoo-offline.sig --no-checksum --bundle cuckoo-offline.zip` This will fetch the package and all it's dependencies.
6. Finally copy the zip file cuckoo-offline.zip using an USB-Stick to your **NON-Networked** Notebook and run this command there: `sudo apt-offline install cuckoo-offline.zip`

Of course you can do this for updates/upgrades and for other packages.

[How to Update/Upgrade Your Ubuntu Without Internet Connection](http://www.maketecheasier.com/update-upgrade-ubuntu-without-internet-connection/2012/07/10)

Comment: The only problem in this method is that, the networked machine runs Windows... So I can't use `apt-offline` on it.

Comment: You could run an Ubuntu Life-CD on your Windows machine or install apt-offline under Windows; needs Python 2.7.2 and apt-offline for Windows (zip) http://www.python.org/download/ https://alioth.debian.org/frs/download.php/3854/apt-offline-1.3.zip

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install all .deb packages

Comment: This will install all the packages. I want to install one program out of the two, with all its dependencies.

Comment: Create a directory and move the .deb you don't want to install there;

Comment: But how will I know that I am not moving any package that is a dependency for the package I want to install?

Comment: When you issue the command dpkg -i a.deb it will tell you that it is missing dependencies!

Comment: I know that. But don't you think it'll be a tiring job to separate all dependencies....? I am looking for something automatic.

Comment: Why do you need .deb in the first place? It the package not available from a repository?

Comment: The thing is, my laptop doesn't have a Internet connection. So I use Synaptic Package Manager to generate download scripts and download them from a different computer. The problem is, I kept all the packages in the same directory... And hence the trouble. I think you can understand my problem.